# Функция replace для строки

Tags: python, pycharm

Я новичок в питоне, хочу узнать, когда у нас есть какой-нибудь цикл или функция, например

`if '722' in s: s = s.replace('722', '57', 1)`
почему нам надо писать s = s.replace? Почему нельзя сразу вызвать функцию без присвоения значения этой строке? Вопрос чисто из любопытства, чтобы понять как это работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм... Потому что метод-функция **возвращает новую строку** с изменениями, а не модифицирует старую - ведь в Python строки неизменяемые ("immutable")

Comment: Все понял, спасибо